# What would be the abilities of a wave function collapsing oracle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

Although the [Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell's_theorem) dismiss local hidden variables as an explanation of the quantum variability, there is nothing to prevent an observer to see the occurrence of a wave function collapse as the expression of a (still) transcendental will of an oracle. For example such an oracle could be able to trigger the radioactive decay or spontaneous light emission of any given atom. This oracle should be be "locally" constrained  by the laws of quantum mechanics by providing the expected probability distributions for the waves collapses. But It should also be "globally" constrained by the texture of the quantum noise which should "look like blank noise". Hash functions or encrypted texts produce [such blank noise](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145633/179663), and one could as well see this constraint as the oracle's way to conceal its wills.

As pointed out by other members the question was quite unclear even for me, it was just a provocative (or so I thought) showerthought. So let me summarise and be a bit more precise. Can we imagine an oracle as an external/transcendental will that manage the decoherence processes across the universe (a non local hidden variable theory) and would conceal its goals within the quantum noise.

Imagine a universe that would be a composed of one randomly evolving letter. The physicists in this universe would try to design a theory to model the probability of the next letter to appear. Well if the oracle of this universe was streaming an AES256 encryption of Romeo and Juliet there would be a concealed pattern within the apparent randomness.

Now as we model the macroscopic world as a deterministic dynamical system this pattern of de-coherence on a longer time scale could have some macroscopic effects ("chaos theory").

And given the still unexplained emergence of life as we know it, this could be a reasonable argument for believers to justify the existence of such an all-mighty oracle willing to create life thought its mastery of de-coherence and chaos theory at macroscopic scale. I have still no good question but this (soft) one : how would you respond as a (meta-)physicist to such an argument ?

At last, I must say that the locality notion is provided by the general relativity which, from what I've heard, doesn’t mix well with the quantum world. Therefore I am pretty certain the story is ill-defined in many ways and this may be more of a poet's exercise to the glory of our all-mighty oracle.

Comment: *Nota Bene*: I did not study quantum mechanic so the above description might well include some of my misconceptions. Furthermore as a non-native English writer, this text will almost certainly include some grammatical errors as well. Feel free to let me know about it.

Comment: The trouble is that you're assuming such an oracle can exist then asking what would its properties would be. The real question is *can such an oracle exist?* to which the answer is *no*. It makes no sense to ask what the properties of a non-existant system are.

Comment: @JohnRennie I said in the end that the question could be ill-defined. But can you explain further why such a system could not exist ? (you can write this as an answer...at least it is ok for me) Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that such an 'oracle' would be just another way to state an hidden variable model, which we know is ruled out by Bell's theorem (unless we accept non-local theories). I'd therefore see the existence of such an 'oracle' as simply implying that Bell's inequalities would not be violated (while we know by experiments that they are, modulo technicalities), and therefore that quantum mechanics is wrong.

Comment: @glance Absolutely, that is a way to state a non local theory (it has to be because of the Bell's inequality as I said in the beginning). That is an argument religious people could make. What I am asking is what miracles could such a "being" produced. ;)

Comment: @matovitch so your question is: what would be the consequences of having a nonlocal theory? To that I would answer that in some sense even quantum mechanics can be recast as a deterministic nonlocal theory (see [De Broglie-Bohm theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory)) so that is not something conceptually absurd. So I guess if the question is *what miracles could a deterministic nonlocal theory produce* the answer is *quantum mechanics*.

Comment: @glance Thanks for your link. That was just a showerthought. For example the oracle could not make a ball go through a wall, because that would heavily affect the texture of the quantum noise around the ball. However it may be able by small unnoticeable quantum modifications and chaos theory to affect the future with macroscopic effect.

Comment: @matovitch *that would heavily affect the texture of the quantum noise (...) small unnoticeable quantum modifications and chaos theory* -> I really have no idea what that means

Comment: @glance (again) That is more my question. (BTW I was doing some proselytism to launch my religion too. There are no specific commandments to obey. Currently hiring for an apostle job if you are interested. ;))

Comment: @glance Sorry I wasn't being serious in my last comment. An other formulation would be. Such an oracle would not do an improbable miracle where improbable is given by the laws we knows (or with the probability we expect). But could however affect the world by other means (chaos theory).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31903/discussion-between-matovitch-and-glance).

Comment: If I get it right your idea is that we could imagine a metaphysical structure in the probabilist nature of QM: instead of random measurement outcomes, we would have clever transcendental outcomes mimicking randomness while really conspiring to effect the universe in a meaningful way. IMO what would be the main miracle in that situation is precisely that the natural world would have meaning. About what you call quantum noise, no need to assume it should be blank when it is not being monitored: we cannot do reproducible experiments on miracles. DISCLAIMER: This is all pure playful speculation !

Comment: It's the idea. Although in my mind, transcendental (aka. not understandable from a human view point) is equivalent to "truly" random. If there is a "meaning", it is not transcendental. Even though maybe it still is from the current perspective. One could define a universe as meaningful if it is Kolmogorov compressible. In the R&J example the zip of the text + the aes256 key is a compression so the universe has a meaning. But a compressed universe there is no way alaw of physics could predict the next letter or it would be compressible. This is transcendental from its inhabitants perspective.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin I see your point about the blank noise. But what's "fun" is that maybe such oracle don't need to affect the texture of the noise to have a tremendous macroscopic effect. The use of chaos theory would be enough. As you say this is just a pure playful speculation.

Comment: Replace "meaning" with "intent" if you prefer. An oracle having abilities (as per your question title) definitely has to be endowed with some intent, else I really cannot see how its actions would be anything else than random in any conceptualizable way; and then of course there would be no reason to invoke the existence of such an oracle. The point of the notion of transcendance is to provide a higher point of view. If transcendance has no meaning in human terms, then it is pointless to use this notion. Now what is the meaning of "meaning" ? Here is a transcendant question...

Comment: Well oracle was in my mind a generic term, I did not suppose a being with intent (it could be a simple entropy source). But yes the question was if it had an intent what would it be able to do with a strict respect of known physical laws (hence the noise constraints). As for trancendent just replace it with (pure) random. The idea  is that you cannot justify the réalisation of an abstract mathematical random variable. But yes in my post I was using a relative transcendence in the sensé that one do not have an explanation now, not that its pure unexplanable random.